# Nervgh Angular File Upload - cancelItem method not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

This is my html code :

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" options="{ photoType: 'studentPic' }" uploader="uploader" />
```

This is angular code :

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: 'badges/photos',
            autoUpload: true
        });

        // FILTERS

        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'customFilter',
            fn: function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/ , options) {                
                return this.queue.length < 10;
            }
        });

        // CALLBACKS

        uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/ , filter, options) {
            console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function (addedFileItems) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
        };
        uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
            console.log("item before uploading:",item._file.type);
            console.log("item before uploading:",item._file.size);
            if((item._file.type!="image/png" && item._file.type!="image/jpeg") || item._file.size>102400){
                console.log("in if of before");
                this.cancelItem(item);
            }            
            console.log(item.photoType);
            var filename = generateUUID();
            if (item.photoType === 'studentPic') {
                $scope.pic = filename;
            }
            if (item.photoType === 'pickupPerson1Pic') {
                $scope.pickupPerson1Pic = filename;
            }
            if (item.photoType === 'pickupPerson2Pic') {
                $scope.pickupPerson2Pic= filename;
            }
            item.formData.push({
                filename: filename
            });
            console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
        };
        uploader.onProgressItem = function (fileItem, progress) {
            console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
        };
        uploader.onProgressAll = function (progress) {
            console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
        };
        uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            if (fileItem.photoType === 'studentPic') {
                angular.element('#picPreview').attr("src", response.url);
            }
            if (fileItem.photoType === 'pickupPerson1Pic') {
                angular.element('#pickupPerson1PicPreview').attr("src", response.url);
            }
            if (fileItem.photoType === 'pickupPerson2Pic') {
                angular.element('#pickupPerson2PicPreview').attr("src", response.url);
            }
            console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onErrorItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCancelItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteAll = function () {
            console.info('onCompleteAll');
        };
```

My uploader.onBeforeUploadItem has the condition if((item._file.type!="image/png" && item._file.type!="image/jpeg") || item._file.size>102400) and if it succeeds the I call the this.cancelItem(item) method.

```
 uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
                console.log("item before uploading:",item._file.type);
                console.log("item before uploading:",item._file.size);
                if((item._file.type!="image/png" && item._file.type!="image/jpeg") || item._file.size>102400){
                    console.log("in if of before");
                    this.cancelItem(item);
                }            
                console.log(item.photoType);
                var filename = generateUUID();
                if (item.photoType === 'studentPic') {
                    $scope.pic = filename;
                }
                if (item.photoType === 'pickupPerson1Pic') {
                    $scope.pickupPerson1Pic = filename;
                }
                if (item.photoType === 'pickupPerson2Pic') {
                    $scope.pickupPerson2Pic= filename;
                }
                item.formData.push({
                    filename: filename
                });
                console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
            };
```

Now am I calling the cancel Item method wrongly? Because despite the conditions matching the upload of the item still continues successfully.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

this.cancelItem(item) will cancel uploads that are already in progress.

You need to check the conditions before you upload the file.

So, for example:

```
<button type="button" id="upLoadFileButton" data-ng-click="validateStuffBeforeUpload(item)">Upload File</button>
```

And then in your controller you have the function where you validate what you want to validate and then on success you call the uploadItem method and pass in the file item:

```
    $scope.validateStuffBeforeUpload = function (fileItem) {
            if((item._file.type!="image/png" && item._file.type!="image/jpeg") || item._file.size>102400){
                console.log("in if of before");
            } else {
                uploader.uploadItem(fileItem);
            }
        };
```

Or some variation of that... in any case, that you need to validate what you want before you call the uploadItem method.